# Monitor file change in AutoHotkey without a loop or timer

Tags: autohotkey

I am interested in having an .ahk file reloaded automatically whenever it changes. The reason is that I am hosting my .ahk files in Google Drive, and so the script may be changed on a running computer without the user (me, mostly) taking notice.

I have found a number of possible solutions, some examples:
[WatchDirectory()](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/41653-watchdirectory/)
[newer version](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/60125-ahk-lv2-watchdirectory-report-directory-changes/)
[Folder Spy](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/21086-crazy-scripting-folderspy-v096-synchronous/)

Despite my problems of making them work on a Windows-10,AutoHotkey-1.1 maschine, they all involve some kind of loop.  [#AutoReload](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/30553-autoreload-automatically-reload-changes-to-a-script/) was proposed, but apparently never implemented. I am used to C# programming, so I am always thinking "events" and "event handlers".

Is there a straightforward way to passively subscribe to file changes, that is, without running infinite loops?

Comment: For your scenario with Google Drive there is no reason not to use a loop first and upgrade it later if you find an event-based approach you like more.  I run an auto-reload check that is loop-based but runs as fast or as slow as desired with no real performance hit, although obviously it uses incrementally more CPU and I/O if it's executed at 100 times a second vs. 1 time a second.  The loop just checks the file attributes in a directory and launches a reload for any files that have been saved--very efficient and elegant, although I'm not sure where I first ran into that method on the forums.